# Difference between \uXXXX, \uuXXXX and \uuuXXXX

Tags: java, jls

Following line is from [JLS §3.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.3):

> If an eligible \ is followed by u , **or more than one u** , and the last u is not followed
> by four hexadecimal digits, then a compile-time error occurs.

So this means the following lines will result the same:

```
System.out.println('\u0065');   // prints "e"
System.out.println('\uu0065');  // prints "e"
System.out.println('\uuu0065'); // prints "e"
```

Using a single `u` in `\uXXXX` essentially does the same as using `uu` in `\uuXXXX`. My question is, why do we need this kind of design?

Answer (score 5):

The reason is stated a little bit later in the section quoted:

> The Java programming language specifies a standard way of transforming a program written in Unicode into ASCII that changes a program into a form that can be processed by ASCII-based tools. The transformation involves converting any Unicode escapes in the source text of the program to ASCII by adding an extra u - for example, \uxxxx becomes \uuxxxx - while simultaneously converting non-ASCII characters in the source text to Unicode escapes containing a single u each.

This means it makes the conversion to ASCII fully reversible because you know which escape sequences were originally in the code and which were added by the conversion.

Answer (score 5):

[The answer by Henry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48321745/6099347) gives complete information but not in layman terms.

What happens behind the scene is that every character in the source is converted to Unicode escape sequences. So when we write something like this:

```
ሴ
```

it gets converted to:

```
\u1234 // Escape sequence for `ሴ` is `\u1234`.
```

Now, when we write:

```
\u1234ሴ
```

it gets converted to:

```
\uu1234\u1234
```

This is done for backward compatibility. By using this kind of procedure, we can restore the original ASCII characters from escape sequences.

Escape sequence entered in source code like for ex `\u1234` will get `uu` and replaced to `\uu1234` while the character without escape sequence gets a single `u` and hence `ሴ` will result in `\u1234`.

The following line is from the same section i.e. [JLS §3.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.3):

> The character produced by a Unicode escape does not participate in further Unicode escapes.

These paragraphs make more sense now:

> The Java programming language specifies a standard way of transforming a
> program written in Unicode into ASCII that changes a program into a form that can be processed by ASCII-based tools. The transformation involves converting any Unicode escapes in the source text of the program to ASCII by adding an extra u - for example, \uxxxx becomes \uuxxxx - while simultaneously converting non-ASCII characters in the source text to Unicode escapes containing a single u each.

> This transformed version is equally acceptable to a Java compiler and represents the exact same program. **The exact Unicode source can later be restored from this ASCII form by converting each escape sequence where multiple u 's are present to a sequence of Unicode characters with one fewer u**, while simultaneously converting each escape sequence with a single u to the corresponding single Unicode character.